# Can neutrinos become positron, antimuon and anti-tau-ons?

Tags: particle-physics

Somehow, this thought never occurred to me until tonight....

A neutrino (or antineutrino) can become a positron, antimuon or antitauon just as easily as a normal particle, correct?

Do detectors detect this?

Are antineutrino more likely to become antiparticles? (I'm assuming not....)

Does this have anything to do with neutrinos possibly being Majorana particles?

Comment: What do you mean by “become”? A neutrino, all by itself, turns into one of those more massive particles? That can’t happen.

Comment: The answer is a straight "no".

Comment: Mass-energy conservation permitting (and the right conditions generally aren't going to include a single neutrino hanging out by itself), a neutrino can emit a W boson or a Z boson, which can in turn decay into all sorts of stuff.

Comment: What's a "normal particle"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A neutrino (or antineutrino) can become a positron, antimuon or antitauon just as easily as a normal particle, correct?

Not really. There is lepton number conservation and an electron neutrino can carry the electron number in an interaction, that is all. There is no becoming.

The same holds for all three types of leptons, [here is a feyman](http://inspirehep.net/record/1236362/plots) diagram showing this:

[image]

> Diagram of 2-body scattering between an incoming muon neutrino with 4-momentum pν and an electron at rest with 4-momentum pe.

You ask:

> Are antineutrino more likely to become antiparticles?

Antiparticles of particles appear when lepton conservation is needed.  In the diagram, if a positron were the target, the outgoing would be an electron antineutrino and a mu+ with a W- exchange to keep charge conservation.

> Does this have anything to do with neutrinos possibly being Majorana particles?

No, that is another story, a [different model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorana_fermion) then the [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model).

> also referred to as a Majorana particle, is a fermion that is its own antiparticle.
>
> Because particles and antiparticles have opposite conserved charges, Majorana fermions have zero charge. All of the elementary fermions of the Standard Model have gauge charges, so they cannot have fundamental Majorana masses.
>
> With the exception of the neutrino, all of the Standard Model fermions are known to behave as Dirac fermions at low energy (after electroweak symmetry breaking), and none are Majorana fermions. The nature of the neutrinos is not settled – they may be either Dirac or Majorana fermions.

.....

> Because particles and antiparticles have opposite conserved charges, Majorana fermions have zero charge. All of the elementary fermions of the Standard Model have gauge charges, so they cannot have fundamental Majorana masses.
>
> However, the right-handed sterile neutrinos introduced to explain neutrino oscillation could have Majorana masses

Answer (score 1):

Anti-neutrino interactions with ordinary matter can produce "anti" particles.<sup>1</sup>

> Do detectors detect this?

Yes. They can and regularly do. Exactly how you go about discriminating between "normal" and "anti" particles depends on the detector technology, but this is very important in atmospheric and beam experiments where the neutrino flux has significant admixtures of both kinds.

---

<sup>1</sup> Your use of "become" is ambiguous and I would discourage it in favor of stating more precisely what you mean. Here I have assumed you mean that when (anti-)neutrinos interact with matter, the products of those interactions are charge-conjugation pairs of one another. That is, if an neutrino undergoes interaction X and produces a muon, and anti-neutrino undergoing the same interaction would produce an anti-muon.

This is true up to a point. The limit arises because sometimes it depends on the anti-neutrinos being able to find anti-targets to interact with (not impossible because nucleons in some sense "contain" anti-quarks as well as quarks). As a result the cross-sections are generally not exactly those for ordinary neutrinos producing ordinary products.